# How to remove "admin.php?page=" from wp-admin using .htaccess?

Tags: url-rewriting, wp-admin, htaccess

I'm looking to use `.htaccess` to rewrite admin page URLs. I'd like to change it from:

```
http://example.com/wp-admin/admin.php?page=whatever&id=5&var=10
```

to

```
http://example.com/wp-admin/whatever?id=5&var=10
```

Right now I have:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^members$ admin.php?page=members& [L,E=CLEAN_CONTACT_URL:1,QSA]
RewriteRule ^add-members$ admin.php?page=add-members [L,E=CLEAN_CONTACT_URL:1,QSA]
RewriteRule ^delete$ admin.php?page=delete& [L,E=CLEAN_CONTACT_URL:1,QSA]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^page=(.*)$
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_CLEAN_CONTACT_URL} !1
RewriteRule ^admin.php$ /wp-admin/%1?%2 [R,L]
```

Which changes it to:

```
http://example.com/wp-admin/whatever&id=5&var=10
```

I don't mind adding each 'section' (e.g. members / add-member / delete) to my `.htaccess`. Although, if there is a better way, I'd be happy to see it!

I'm using internal and external redirections, so that when you click on a admin URL and it goes to `wp-admin/admin.php?page=somewhere`, it rewrites the URL for the browser, and then finds the rewritten URL. I would like to use 'pretty' admin links. Example:

```
http://example.com/wp-admin/members
```

Is easy to remember and intuitive. Eventually, I will rename `/wp-admin` to `/user` as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this (sorry, not previously tested). See comments inline for explanation:

```
RewriteEngine On

## if any string separated by | is matched, it will append to ?page=
RewriteRule ^(members|add-members|delete)$ admin.php?page=%1 [L,E=CLEAN_CONTACT_URL:1,QSA]

## If querystring starts with page= and is followed by any string separated by |
## put that in the first group. Then put any other characters in second group
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^page=(members|add-members|delete)(.*)$
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_CLEAN_CONTACT_URL} !1
RewriteRule ^admin.php$ /wp-admin/%1?%2 [R,L]
```

You can probably rewrite the rule to be more generic. The main issue you're having with:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^page=(.*)$
```

is that the `(.*)$` matches ALL characters including your subsequent `&foo=bar` so the entire querystring is lumped into `%1` and your `%2` is empty.

Answer (score -1):

Not really sure on what you want your end goal to look like, but from I understand, here's my approach. In your `.htaccess` add the following rule in between the `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>` tag:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)page=(.*)
RewriteRule ^wp-admin/admin.php(.*)$  wp-admin [R=301,L]]
```

Based off of the default `.htaccess` generated by WordPress, it should now look like the following with your custom `RewriteRule`:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
# Custom Rules
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)page=(.*)
RewriteRule ^wp-admin/admin.php(.*)$  wp-admin [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

This will then redirect pages such as:

```
http://example.com/wp-admin/admin.php?page=whatever&id=5&var=10
```

to

```
http://example.com/wp-admin?page=whatever&id=5&var=10
```

If you could clarify your question specifically on what you want your expected results to be based on some example URLs, I could give you a more concrete answer.